# Log in fails when stored password is incorrect, doesn't prompt

Tags: support, login, openid

It just happened to me that I can't log in on StackOverflow (or any StackExchange site) using "Log In with Google Account" (haven't tried with the other options), apparently because the stored password for my google account was wrong. It said "Welcome back JBL, you're being redirected" but the redirection ends up on the main page, not logged in, and never asked for my password. I tried multiple time and got the same result, which I only managed to fix by wiping the whole cache, and logging in properly on Google before.

Is it supposed to be like that? Couldn't it ask for the password if the stored one is wrong?

Comment: The password is not stored anywhere in Stack Exchange, they're just using Google as OpenID provider.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I know, but when you log in for the first time with Google, they redirect to the Google Login page, where you can enter your login/password. In this case, it seems it can't log in but fails to redirect to this page (while still knowing who I am, as the redirection message clearly uses my nickname). Then, I don't know OpenID enough to really know what it could be exaclty (and that's quite why I ask as well)

Comment: I don't know either for sure, but looks like this is a problem on Google side. Maybe Stack Exchange can handle those corner cases better e.g. show proper message instead of just redirecting to home page, dunno.

Comment: Yep, was thinking the same. At the moment, it just keeps telling you you're logged while it's not the case, and doesn't really let you know why...